# PHP __autoload Cannot redeclare 

Tags: php, autoload

I started to use the PHP __autoload function and now I'm getting those weird Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class xxx errors.

It's weird since these errors occur on classes I don't even load with the autoload function. And I also use require_once to include the files.

I'm really puzzled about this. Anyone knows anything about this kind of errors when using autoload?

Comment: Can you post some example code?

Comment: I get an error "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare randomstring() (previously declared in /var/www/vhosts/businessgame.be/httpdocs/new/functions/function.random.php:24) in /var/www/vhosts/businessgame.be/httpdocs/new/functions/function.random.php on line 34"
The weird thing is, the error does not occur when I manually include a file Bank.php, but this file doesn't contain the function or doesn't even uses it :P.

Raise your hand if you're clueless ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently when it wanted to include Bank class, it took the "bank.php" file from the current directory ^^. Which is just the bank page, it should have include "src/model/Bank.php". I removed the current directory from the search list and it has been fixed.

So always make sure the autoload function is including the correct files. Good practice is too name your files more straightforward like class.Bank.php or class.User.php instead of Bank.php or User.php.

Thanks for your help and quick response anyway!

Comment: So it wasn't the required_once that was the problem but it was just including the wrong file ^^

Comment: Yay for figuring it out, I don't think changing your entire file naming convention for a one off fairly obvious error makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

`require_once`/`include_once` only looks at the file name when they're trying to include a file, not a class name. So you can have class `Foo` in both Foo.php and B.php, and then you'll get that error.

I'm not sure how `__autoload` would cause you any problems, unless `__autoload` requires Foo.php because it needs class `Foo`, and you require B.php manually which redefines class `Foo`.

By the way, use [`spl_autoload_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) instead of `__autoload`.

Comment: The file names are correct. It's just that it claims to have loaded a class already when it actually didn't. When I keep track of the classes being loaded, I notice no doubles.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on spl_autoload_register! Helped me out.

Answer (score 4):

i had same situation .. all i changed was and its working for me

```
include('xxx.php');
```

to

```
require_once('xxx.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not pretend on the best answer. Just my thoughts.

__autoload() is deprecated in PHP 7.2 and will be possiblly deleted.

I found this way to upload/include files

```
//initialize a function which will upload files
function upload(){//you can call the function as you like
  //your path to files goes here
}

spl_autoload_register('upload')//specify the function, where you include your files(in this case it's upload function
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this before, not sure what caused it though. Make sure you're using `require_once`/`include_once` rather than the normal versions for starters. I think the problem was related to using `class_exists` without telling it to skip autoloading (`class_exists($name, false)`) - are you doing this?

Comment: But autoload is only called when a class does not exist? I've tracked the files the autoloading class includes, and I don't see any doubles. It's a weird error.